# Taking XLSX JSON format and turning it into a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table, xlsx

Im taking and XLSX file turning it into JSON to them create a dynamic table to display in HTML. Im somewhat new to JSON so please bear with me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
  <style>
    th,
    td,
    p,
    input {
      font: 14px Verdana;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: solid 1px #DDD;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 2px 3px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
  var json_object = {};
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          document.getElementById("fileContent").innerHTML = json_object;
          //console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          jQuery('#xlx_json').val(json_object);
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }



  function CreateTableFromJSON() {

    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json_object.length; i++) {
      for (var key in json_object[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          col.push(key);
        }
      }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < json_object.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.innerHTML = json_object[i][col[j]];
      }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
  <p id="showData"></p>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
  </form>


  <pre id="fileContent"></pre>


  <script>
    document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want is the JSON output to be translated into a dynamic table. I've tried manually inputting an array of data and im able to get a table. Also tried outputting the data first on the xlsx sheet

```
 document.getElementById("fileContent").innerHTML = myBooks;
```

and i'm able to see the JSON string

Comment: you've told us what you want...but what's the question? What is going wrong with your code currently when you try? Also...is there any specific reason you need the intermediate step of converting the data to JSON? Why not just create the HTML table directly from the Excel data as you read it?

Comment: Having made it into a runnable snippet, it's clearer that one of your main issues (there may be others yet to be discovered) is that `myBooks` is not defined outside the `ExcelToJSON` function, and is therefore not accessible from the `CreateTableFromJSON` function. Would it not make sense to a) make CreateTableFromJSON accept the myBooks array as an input parameter and b) call CreateTableFromJSON from inside ExcelToJSON as soon as it has successfully read the file, rather than waiting for a separate button press? (This is notwithstanding my remark above re the necessity of using JSON)

Comment: ok, so i made `json_object` global but im receiving an one column table with just my JSON string in it. if I set the object value manually i'm able to get the type of table I want.  for instance adding `var json_object = [
    {
        "Book ID": "1",
        "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
        "Category": "Computers",
        "Price": "125.60"
    },
    {
        "Book ID": "2",
        "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
        "Category": "Programming",
        "Price": "56.00"
    }
] `

Comment: I've also update the initial post to what im working with now @ADyson

Comment: Ah ok I see the issue now. Answer added below

Answer (score 0):

You can just change

```
json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object)
```

to

```
json_object = XL_row_object
```

You don't actually need JSON here at all. JSON is a text format by which you can represent data.  So when you do `JSON.stringify` the result is (as per the name) a **string**, not an array or object. When you loop through a string, it iterates each character of the string individually. If you simply leave the array which came from the Excel file as-is without turning it into a string, you can loop through it properly.

JSON is useful for transmitting data (e.g. in a HTTP request) or storing it. But it's not useful for actual data processing, which is what you're doing here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
  <style>
    th,
    td,
    p,
    input {
      font: 14px Verdana;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: solid 1px #DDD;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 2px 3px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
  var json_object = {};
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          json_object = XL_row_object;
          document.getElementById("fileContent").innerHTML = json_object;
          //console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          jQuery('#xlx_json').val(json_object);
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }



  function CreateTableFromJSON() {

    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json_object.length; i++) {
      for (var key in json_object[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          col.push(key);
        }
      }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < json_object.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.innerHTML = json_object[i][col[j]];
      }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
  <p id="showData"></p>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
  </form>


  <pre id="fileContent"></pre>


  <script>
    document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```